# More than 1 way to run C# code on visual studio code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I just wondered about compiling c# code on vs code, because I recently installed dotnet core and they said type "dotnet run" to run the code, but I also can compile c# code with terminal in vs code by typing "mcs fileName.cs" and run with "mono fileName.exe". I just want to know that what is mono and mcs that use to run c# code? And which one is better for me to use to compile c# code? Also is mono & mcs be part of dotnet core?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono

Comment: @DarjanBogdan Thank YOU!!!