# How to create a .NET function code zip file for AWS Lambda function using Mono?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, mono, aws-lambda

I'm new to Mono and .NET ecosystem in general and [the official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dotnet-coreclr-deployment-package.html) doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: The official guide applies to .net Core, is there a (good) reason not to use that?

Comment: Also; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the guide does apply, but I had to install `dotnet-cli` first ([see how](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/Documentation/specs/cli-installation-scenarios.md#osxlinux-shell-command)) which does not come with Mono distribution on OS X.

Also I need a function zip file itself rather than the ability to create a function, which is not the usual or recommended workflow of course.

Building such a zip from docker container:

```
FROM mono
RUN curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin
COPY src /src
WORKDIR /src
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT 1
RUN /root/.dotnet/dotnet publish LambdaTest/LambdaTest.csproj
RUN zip -r -j dotnet.zip LambdaTest/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish/
```

File structure:

```
src/LambdaTest
├── Function.cs
└── LambdaTest.csproj
```

Function.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

    // Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
    [assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

    namespace dotnet
    {
        public class Function
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="input"></param>
            /// <param name="context"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
            {
                return input?.ToUpper();
            }
        }
    }
```

LambdaTest.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to the *"Mono and .NET eco system"*, I strongly advise you to use `.NET Core`.

The `.NET Core` ecosystem is able to deploy a self contained environment, which is needed for most cloud services, such as AWS Lambda (as you can read in the guide you provided).

You can start `.NET Core` projects out of the box when using Visual Studio 2017, and there are template packages available on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Templates) .

More info can be found here, in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-creating-project-in-visual-studio.html):

Comment: I see. I think I could've used .NET Core as well, it occurs to me now that .NET Core vs Mono difference is not the reason why I had difficulties with the guide.