# Selecting the right framework for a ConsoleApp on Mono

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, mono, .net-4.7

I need to develop a ConsoleApp that will run on Windows as well as a RaspberryPi (Raspbian - Debian 9)

I have installed mono-complete on the RaspPi

Now my question is this.  Do I create in Visual Studio a consoleApp for .net Core or a consoleApp for .net framework?

Does mono support .net Core?  If so up to which version?

Looking at the compatibility page ( https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ ) I can't see any reference to .net Core, just the .Net framework.

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core and Mono are on separate tracks, Mono is a cross platform adapter for the full .NET, where .NET Core was initially introduced a set of essential classes from the .NET which is an open source and also a cross platform library.

For detailed comparison I recommend this thread [.NET Core vs Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono)

So in short ;) you can either use .NET Core or Mono.