# How to get VB.NET for Mono set up?

Tags: vb.net, mono

I'm trying to get a Mono development environment set up on a Windows box. Basic install was dead simple, but I'd like to get the VB.NET compiler set up. Only problem is, there doesn't seem to be an installer for it. The [official page on VB.NET support](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/) implies that there should be, but there isn't; it hasn't been incorporated into the main installer, either. I can download the source package from [the mono-basic Github,](https://github.com/mono/mono-basic) but since the compiler is self-hosting, that just leaves me in a catch-22 situation where I need the compiler to compile the compiler... :/ On top of which, it doesn't look like the compiler code has been touched in a couple years...is this still supported? Is there *any* way to get it set up apart from doing a build from source on a machine with the official VS toolchain (or a Linux box with the package installed from a repository) and then copying it over?

Comment: The compiler for Visual Basic.net is included in with Visual Studio. Have you installed Visual Studio? There is a free version for individual developers called Community.

Comment: Maybe this link will help. https://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I figured I'd end up having to do. Just very odd to me that they'd have a self-hosting compiler but neither include it nor provide the separate installer package they apparently used to have...

Comment: Orrrr.. you could write vb.net apps in visual studio on windows, compile them and run the resulting exes in mono on linux?

Comment: Also an option, but I'd prefer to avoid VS altogether if I can, since it's such a pig.

Comment: I get the impression, from [.NET Core vs Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37738106/1115360), that .NET Core (soon to be just .NET) is the way to go now, not Mono.