# Linux application with Realm database

Tags: linux, database, architecture, realm

I build an application in Windows in C# with a Realm database with success. I need as well to support a Linux (i.e. Ubuntu) environment.

Please, what options/suggestions I have to build similar application in Linux? For example, which programming language could I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem ? 
You mean you never heard of [.NET Core or mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono/39740592) ? 
You can use C# right on Linux.  
If you need a UI framework, you can either go with [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net) or [GTK#](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/). 
[Gtk# on Github](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp)
[Avalonia on Github](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia)

Realm.io states:

> .NET Core 2.0 or later on: 
>   - Ubuntu 16.04 or later 
>   - Debian 8 or later
>   - RHEL 7.1 or later 
>   - macOS 10.11 or later 
>   - Windows 8.1 or later

Source: https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest

Comment: thanks for your feedback and references. Especially the reference to .NET Core vs Mono.