# Dockerfile for ASP.NET Core + Angular app

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, proxy, dockerfile

I am trying to use Docker with the VS sample of ASP.NET Core app and its Angular client but I cannot manage to find a working configuration (neither on Linux nor Windows containers).

Here is the project tree :
[image]

here is the SPA proxy conf :

```
"name": "project2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44419 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44419 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Project2:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
...
```

and the generated dockerfile looks like this :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project3.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./Project3.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Project3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project3.dll"]
```

When I run it and try to access to localhost:44419, I do get an empty response. What do I miss please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on same setup as you ASP.NET(not core) + Angular.
I was working with iis base docker image instead of aspnet which i tried many times without success.

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY content/ .
```

Here in this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/iis-docker/tree/main/samples) are some simples to setup your asp.net core.

Another thing i want to mention is this setup which i provide to you works just in windows based systems.

But there is another setup based on [Mono project](https://www.mono-project.com) (instead of iis) to be run in the linux based systems ( this way doesn't work for me till the moment i stopped working with that company )

reference: [.NET Core vs Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono)

Best regards